# How to revive the general options in TeXstudio without reinstalling it

Tags: texstudio

I use TeXstudio 2.12.4 on Windows 7.

Here are the steps to reproduce the problem: I went to the `Options\Configure` TeXstudio option. I clicked the checkbox `Show Advanced Options`, then accessed the `Menus` item. Then I clicked the checkbox `Show All`, then accidentally, I clicked the button to hide the `Configure TeXstudio` item.

I didn't notice this at first but when I clicked OK but forgot to change something, the `Configure TeXstudio` option is lost. I did a Google search, and all the results were completely irrelevant and that I was desperate enough to search for into the 5th page of results. I searched the TeX.SE site but nothing came out.

How can I reaccess the `Configure TeXstudio` option without resetting TeXstudio, or reinstalling it?

Maybe a command-line approach is possible, but I need to access the `Configure TeXstudio` GUI menu box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a script at `Macros -> Edit Macros` to trigger the menu item even when it's not shown:

```
%SCRIPT
app.getManagedAction("main/options/config").trigger()
```

Alternatively, you can manually remove the entry `changedLatexMenus` from [texstudio.ini](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#where-are-the-settings-stored)

Comment: Its seems that I have removed the `Macros -> Edit Macros` option too... so the second one's really a help.